# Mongodb sum, sort and rank

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{_id:123
 "name":"Amy"
"Num_1":NumberInt(2),
"Num_2":NumberInt(4),
"Num_3":NumberInt(0),
"Num_4":NumberInt(4),}
```

Now I have this structure in MongoDB as above, I am wondering how can I have an output that gives me the user's name that has the highest sum of all num (sum of "Num_1","Num_2","Num_3","Num_4")